# React error Warning: render(): Rendering components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Warning: render(): Rendering components directly into document.body is discouraged, since its children are often manipulated by third-party scripts and browser extensions. This may lead to subtle reconciliation issues. Try rendering into a container element created for your app.

what is error??
and what can i do??

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: See [Rendering an element into the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#rendering-an-element-into-the-dom).

Comment: Somewhere you're doing `ReactDOM.render(<YourApp/>, document.body);` Instead, add an element to the HTML (`<div id="root"></div>` or similar) and do `ReactDOM.render(<YourApp/>, document.getElementById("root"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere you're doing

```
ReactDOM.render(<YourApp/>, document.body);
```

Instead, add an element to the HTML (`<div id="root"></div>` or similar) and do

```
ReactDOM.render(<YourApp/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Details in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#rendering-an-element-into-the-dom).

Answer (score 1):

You have something like this in the index.html:

```
<body id="root"></body>
```

This problem occurs because you are trying to use your  tag as React root rendering tree. This way you are likely to get your body tag being manipulated by other 3rd party libs, so that React itself lost its root render tree.

You will need to change it as:

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```